# histogram not showing properly in jupyter

Tags: histogram, jupyter

hope you can help me with a minor problem in jupyter. 
I have a big dataset about people that have bought newspapers and i want to show it in a histogram. the dataset is kinda big with 68000 row and 1 columns. the histogram is giving me all the row values in the x-axis, which i just want to be between 100 and 1200. Because the lowest paper that got sold in a month was 1 and highest 1188. i want to group that so my x axis shows 100-200-300-400-500 and so on till 1200. but its showing all wrong, instead its showing my rows witch goes from 1-68000.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
plt.xlabel('day') 


plt.ylabel('Frequency')  
plt.title('subscription_days')  


x = df[['subscription_days']]

plt.hist(x)

plt.grid(True)  
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Nyf.png)